# Using async/await to return data in hapi.js's handler function

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, hapi.js

I want to return `dataSet` from my handler function. However it's nested inside my promise chain. I'm attempting to use `await/async` but the value of data is still undefined. Thoughts on how to do this?

`handler: (request, h) => {`

```
    let data: any;
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error-------> " + err);
        }
        console.log("Connected as id " + connection.threadId);
        connector.getAllEvents()
            .then(async dataSet => {
                console.log(dataSet);
                data = await dataSet;
            });
    });
    return data;
}
```

Err is not being thrown since logging to the console prints out the values I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do this you would need to make `handler` return a `Promise`, and within the handler, wrap the `connection.connect` block with a `Promise`.

e.g.

```
handler: (request, h) => {
    // wrap connector.connect(...) in a Promise
    return Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.connect(err => {
           if (err) {
               console.error("Error -----> ", err);

               // error in connection, propagate error via reject
               // and do not continue processing
               return reject(err);
           }

           console.log("Connected as id " + connection.threadId);
           connector.getAllEvents()
               // don't think you need this to be async
               // as connector.getAllEvents() will should return a Promise<T>
               // and .then() is like a .map() so its first argument is a T
               // rather than a Promise<T> 
               .then(dataSet => {
                   console.log(dataSet);

                   // we finally have our value
                   // so we propagate it via resolve()
                   resolve(dataSet);
               });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you! this worked. it was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: since you're using `return Promise(res,rej)` to convert a `cb` to a promise you should not need `async` in `async (request,h) => {`   because async functions return a promise.resolve(yourfunctionreturndata), unless there's something funky going on with the scope in hapi

Answer (score 1):

Data is not initialized when you return it. You can test it by adding another log statement just before return, you'll see it prints before `console.log(dataSet);`

I don't know what `connection.connect` returns (what framework is it?), but you can promisify it. Then you either return a promise to "connect and get the data" and let the caller wait on it, or you `await` on it inside your function and return the data after promise is fulfilled.